# Click-thru a virtual function in IDA

Tags: ida

I'm reversing some stuff that has RTTI, so finding vftables is easy.

I have an instance of some class `some_object`, there is a method being called through its `__vftable`. The `method_4` has a type of `data_struct *(__thiscall *method_4)(void *not_sure, data_struct *data_struct, int a3)`. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to actually click on `method_4` here and go to the pointer in the vftable/the underlaying `sub_<something>`? I seem to be stuck just having to go back to the vftable manually when I want to see what that function does.

It feels like I need to somehow link the instance of `some_object` or rather its `_vftable` to the actual vftable memory location but not sure if that's a thing? Do I want too much? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it makes it clickable, but you can use `add_cref` to link a location to another code location.

I typically use this if I have a call site like `call eax` and I know that `eax` always points to the same location (as in your case with vtables).

That way, IDA treats the `call eax` connected to the target location and you get all the benefits like argument propagation, xrefs on the target etc., maybe it makes it clickable but I don't use the decompiler.

Use it like:

```
add_cref(addr_from, addr_to, fl_CN | XREF_USER)
```

if you forget the XREF_USER the code ref is sometimes lost by the auto-analysis if I remember correctly.